# Source.combine doesn't take varargs?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is Akka  trying to communicate that `Source.combine` shouldn't be used with a collection of sources?  Or am I being dumb somehow with the function definition?

Akka `Source.combine` requires a first and second source before vararags. The function definition given below:

```
def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*)(
      strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed]
```

I'd like to just do something like:

```
val sources : Seq[Source[Int,_]] = ???
Source.combine(sources:_*)(Merge(_))
```

I don't know if my `sources` will have 1,2, or many sources. So writing up the cases adds a few lines.  Not a huge deal, but I feel like I'm missing something.  Is this an anti-pattern for akka streams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the pattern `first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*` is to assure that you pass at least 2 (might be more) sources to method.

If method signature allowed `sources:_*` you could be passing empty vararg or with just single element.

In your case, if sources is `Seq`, I would just do pattern matching on sources to split into first and second element and the rest:

```
sources match {
   case first :: second :: rest => Source.combine(first, second, rest:_*)(Merge(_))
   case _ => ??? // too few elements, maybe return Source.failed?
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the Source.combine couldn't return an empty source just like `Source.empty`, or just a copy of the head of the list. I think your explanation and match case is a reasonably concise solution though.